# onRowsPerPageChange not accepted by MUI TablePagination

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

The following MuiTable code works mostly fine, in that I can see the full table content, with the correct column headers, paginating every 5 rows, and the 'Previous'(<) & 'Next'(>) buttons at the bottom correctly steps through the pages too. However changing 'rows per page' from the drop-down doesn't work, in that it has no effect on the table - Items per Page is fixed at 5.

```
import {
  TableContainer,
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableBody,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
  TablePagination,
  TableFooter,
} from '@material-ui/core';

...
const handleChangePage = (_event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> | null, newPage: number) => {setPage(newPage)

const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
      setrowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
      setPage(0);
};

...
return (<>
<TableContainer>
    <Table>
    {/* table heading */}
        <TableHead>{/* omitted for clarify */}</TableHead>
        <TableBody>{/* omitted for clarify */}</TableBody>
        <TableFooter>
            <TableRow>
                <TablePagination
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15]}
                    count={100}
                    rowsPerPage={5}
                    page={page}
                    onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                    onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage} {/* this line triggers error */}
                />
              </TableRow>
            </TableFooter>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
</>)
```

Specifying the `onRowsPerPageChange` handler like above would trigger the following VS Code error:

```
  (property) onRowsPerPageChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & Pick<TableCellProps, "ref" | "align" | "colSpan" | "headers" | "rowSpan" | "scope" | "abbr" | "defaultChecked" | ... 260 more ... | "sortDirection"> & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Property 'component' is missing in type '{ rowsPerPageOptions: (number | { label: string; value: number; })[]; count: number; rowsPerPage: number; page: number; onChangePage: (_event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent> | null, newPage: number) => void; onRowsPerPageChange: (event: ChangeEvent<...>) => void; labelRowsPerPage: string; }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType<any>; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<TablePaginationTypeMap<{}, ComponentType<Pick<TableCellProps, "ref" | "align" | "colSpan" | "headers" | "rowSpan" | "scope" | "abbr" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | ... 258 more ... | "sortDirection">>>>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ rowsPerPageOptions: (number | { label: string; value: number; })[]; count: number; rowsPerPage: number; page: number; onChangePage: (_event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent> | null, newPage: number) => void; onRowsPerPageChange: (event: ChangeEvent<...>) => void; labelRowsPerPage: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DefaultComponentProps<TablePaginationTypeMap<{}, ComponentType<Pick<TableCellProps, "ref" | "align" | "colSpan" | "headers" | "rowSpan" | "scope" | "abbr" | "defaultChecked" | ... 260 more ... | "sortDirection">>>>'.
      Property 'onRowsPerPageChange' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DefaultComponentProps<TablePaginationTypeMap<{}, ComponentType<Pick<TableCellProps, "ref" | "align" | "colSpan" | "headers" | "rowSpan" | "scope" | "abbr" | "defaultChecked" | ... 260 more ... | "sortDirection">>>>'.ts(2769)
```

and console warning:

```
Warning: Unknown event handler property `onRowsPerPageChange`. It will be ignored.
```

Relevant package versions:

```
  "@material-ui/core": "4.11.2",
  "react": "16.14.0",
```

How should `onRowsPerPageChange` be specified for this version of the `TablePagination`, and more importantly, where is the MUI documentation for it (because I would like to apply further styling)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

changing `onRowsPerPageChange` to `onChangeRowsPerPage` fixed the problem!